# how to set a minimum pane size - javafx

Tags: canvas, resize, javafx, minimum, pane

I would like to set a minimum size such as 200x200 so when my pane is resized it cannot be any smaller then the select minimum size. Anyone ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [setMinSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setMinSize%28double,%20double%29) method to set the minimum size of a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html):

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.setMinSize(200, 200);
```